# I'm struggling to connect cross-entropy minimization with likelihood maximization

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, cross-entropy

I am struggling to understand the equivalence between cross-entropy loss and maximum likelihood estimation. I'll present the standard derivation of this equivalence for the simple case of binary classification, followed by my concerns.

---

Consider a binary classification problem. Our training data consist of pairs of $(x_i,y_i)$, where each $y_i$ is either 0 or 1. We model each $y_i$ as a Bernoulli distribution $q$ with parameter $\lambda$:
$$
q(y_i;\lambda) = \begin{cases}
   \lambda & y_i=1, \\
   1-\lambda & y_i = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

The cross-entropy $\operatorname{H}$ of this model relative to the actual observed distribution is $\operatorname{H}(p,q)=-\sum_ip(y_i)\log q(y_i;\lambda)$. The empirically observed probability of a value is its frequency over the training data. Since the cross-entropy sums over the training set, we set $p(y_i)$ to $1/N$, where $N$ is the size of the training set. I'll revisit this argument later.

From here, it is straightforward to show that minimizing the cross-entropy will maximize the likelihood:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\operatorname{H}(p,q) = -\sum_i \frac{1}{N}\log q(y_i;\lambda) \\
-N \cdot \operatorname{H}(p,q) = \sum_i \log q(y_i ; \lambda) = \log \prod_iq(y_i ; \lambda) \\
\ell = -N \cdot \operatorname{H}(p,q).
\end{gathered}
$$

Thus, minimizing the cross-entropy maximizes the log-likelihood $\ell$, which maximizes the likelihood.

---

My issue with the explanation above is that it treats the $y_i$s as belonging to a single probability distribution, when in reality they belong to a *family* of distributions since $\lambda$ will depend on $x$. For example, the training data can have a high probability of being a positive case ($y=1$) when $x$ is close to zero, with a decreasing probability as $x$ tends to $\pm \infty$. It seems to me that the cross-entropy is only defined *for a given value of $x$*. And assigning an empirical probability to the $y$s based on the frequency that they occur *over all values of $x$* seems equally misguided.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: I don't see $x$ in any of your equations; at the moment of my writing this, it would appear to be irrelevant, and there's no reason why $\lambda$ would depend on it.

Comment: @jbowman I omitted $\lambda$'s dependency on $x$ because most textbook derivations do the same. But there _must_ be a dependency on $x$. If I'm classifying images of handwritten digits as either "contains the digit 5" or "does not contain the digit 5", does it make sense to speak of a probability that an image contains a digit 5 independently of the image itself?

Comment: The $y_i$ are random variables not "a Bernoulli distribution" as you write. Also your definition of $q$ makes no sense. You could improve your question with more precise notation (as also mentioned by jbowman)

Comment: It depends on the circumstances.   In your case, you need to model $\lambda(x)$, but in other situations, e.g., testing for the probability that an item is defective, we may well assume a constant probability across all items being tested.  You've written out equations appropriate for the latter situation while being faced with the former, hence your difficulty.